# Limit $\lim_{n \to \infty} (−1)^n (1 + \frac{1 }{ 2n^2})^{n^2}$

Tags: calculus, sequences-and-series, limits

The problem is limit as n approaches infinity $$\lim_{n \to \infty} (−1)^n * (1 + (1 / (2n^2)))^(n^2)$$. What I have done is reduced the right side of the equation to one. Because the right side $$(1 + (1/\infty))^{\infty}$$ just reduces to one. It is the the left side that alternates between 1 and negative 1. My final conclusion was that the limit does not exist because of the alternating on the left side. Maybe I am wrong. Would appreciate some feedback.

Comment: $1^\infty$ is an indeterminate form, you cannot conclude it is $1$

Comment: Please use [MathJax](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020) to format.

Comment: yo, Jeff man, I tried to fix your limit, try a little yourself

Comment: Thanks for fixing my question. I guess you are right Ninad. It is an indeterminate form. I will use MathJax from now on. Thanks everyone. I need a good review of this stuff. It has been a while since I cracked a calculus book.

Answer (score 5):

$(1+\frac1 {2n^{2}})^{n^{2}}=\sqrt {(1+\frac1 {2n^{2}})^{(2n^{2})}} \to \sqrt e$. So the even numbered terms tend to $\sqrt e$ and the odd numbered ones to $-\sqrt e$. Hence the limit does not exist.